# Optimizing a slow For loop

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I know that this is a "beginner question", and, in fact, I am. I want to improve my code, as it takes really too much time to run.
I have already read some other discussions, like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica),
but I am struggling in translating the simplifications with `Table` or `Do` into my example.

The `For` cycle I want to improve is the following:

```
zh = 0.4;
list = {};

For[i = 1, i < 10000, i++, 
    With[{zg = -0.6, dh = i*10^-2}, 
         nsol = Block[{eps = $MachineEpsilon}, 
         NDSolve[{phi''[x] + 2*phi'[x]/x + (2*(zg + zh*Exp[-zh*x/dh])/x + 1)*phi[x] == 0, phi[eps] == 1, phi'[eps] == -(zg + zh)}, phi, {x, eps, 20000}, 
                 WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision, AccuracyGoal->15, PrecisionGoal->8, MaxSteps->Infinity]]];  
    AppendTo[list, 1/Evaluate[(15000*phi[15000])^2 + ((15000-Pi/2)*phi[15000-Pi/2])^2 /. nsol[[1]]]];]
```

Clearly, this code, written in this way, is highly inefficient. Also, I need to do more of these, with different values for `zg` inside `With`, and make some plots out of the lists.

Anyone that can help me with this noob question?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Eliminate the AppendTo inside the loop and use Sow and Reap instead.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: You should take a look at this, if you haven't yet: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12  The documentation of `Sow` and `Reap` has several relevant examples.

Comment: Actually I don't see any need for Sow/Reap here. Just use Table.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have already explicitly written that I had had a look into that link, but that I am not able to use Table in my case.

Comment: Here is a simple example: Reap[
 Do[Sow[i], {i, 5}]
 ].  Note that Reap returns a list of 2 entries, the first one is the result of the expression inside Reap (here: Null), the second is a list of the elements Sow returned.

Comment: I don't see why `Table` wouldn't work—what exactly have you tried? Also, the code you posted here doesn't run (which is why I can't directly give you the `Table` translation). Please show a complete, minimal, working example.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote i=0 as the starting point of the For loop in the question, but it is i=1, this is why it did not work for you. I've just corrected the error. Also, it appears that MMA complains if you define the differential equation before the For cycle, hence I put it dexplicitly inside.

Comment: Yes, `With` does literal replacement. `a = b; With[{b=1}, a]` does not work. You need `Block` for that, not `With`.

Comment: You still didn't explain why this is not a straightforward translation to `Table`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that uses `Table` (well, `ParallelTable`) instead of `For`. I've also used `ParametricNDSolveValue` instead of `With`, mostly to simplify the `Table`.

```
phifunc = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {\[Phi]''[x] + 2 \[Phi]'[x]/x + (2 (zg + zh Exp[-zh x/dh])/x + 1) \[Phi][x] == 0
   , \[Phi][$MachineEpsilon] == 1
   , \[Phi]'[$MachineEpsilon] == -(zg + zh)
   }
  , 1/((15000 \[Phi][15000])^2 + ((15000 - \[Pi]/2) \[Phi][
         15000 - \[Pi]/2])^2)
  , {x, $MachineEpsilon, 20000}
  , {dh \[Element] Reals, zg \[Element] Reals, zh \[Element] Reals}
]
list = ParallelTable[phifunc[i 10^-2, -0.6, 0.4], {i, 1, 10000}]
```

As far as timing goes, it still seems to take a very long time to run 10000 evaluations, so another answer might provide a faster method. I vaguely recall a way to functionalize calls to `NDSolve` in a way that stores calculations for faster repeated calls, but I can't find the link.

Comment: Thank you @Josh Bishop, this looks better! It still takes a lot of time, though..